# Recurse into a templated function after changing the type

Tags: c++, recursion

I am currently writing my own implementation of merge sort for practice. When merging the left and right parts of the list, it makes sense to create a temporary list with only the smaller of the two sides. However, the logic changes depending the side that was copied to a temp.

My function has the following signature:

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void Merge(RandomIt begin, RandomIt middle, RandomIt end, Compare Comp);
```

I had a clever idea to check the lengths of `[begin,middle)` and `[middle,end)` at the beginning, and if the left was bigger, convert the iterators to reverse iterators and recursively call the function. Like this:

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void Merge(RandomIt begin, RandomIt middle, RandomIt end, Compare Comp) {
    size_t leftLength = std::distance(begin, middle);
    size_t rightLength = std::distance(middle, end);

    if (leftLength > rightLength) {
        using ReverseIterator = std::reverse_iterator<RandomIt>;
        Merge(ReverseIterator(end), ReverseIterator(std::next(middle)), ReverseIterator(begin), Comp);
        return;
    }
    //Now [begin,middle) is guaranteed <= [middle,end)
    //...
}
```

However, the compiler gives a pretty thick error.

```
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
```

I've created a [little stand-alone application on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/YVFlzL) that reproduces the error.

EDIT: For mergesort, I just realized that this wont work because the Compare function needs to be reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that, you are creating a new instantiation of the function `Merge` at every step of recursion i.e first time you create a `reverse_iterator` from a `randomaccess_iterator`. Then the compiler creates a `reverse_iterator` from the `reverse_iterator` and so on.....

As you must have noted while creating a `reverse_iterator` the template type of the iterator keeps on changing..thus creating a new instance of your templated function.

In short your use of the iterators is wrong.

This might work:

```
template <class RandomIt, class RevIt>
void Test(RandomIt begin, RandomIt middle, RandomIt end, RevIt rit) {
        size_t leftLength = std::distance(begin, middle);
        size_t rightLength = std::distance(middle, end);
        if (leftLength > rightLength) {
                Test(RevIt(end), RevIt(middle), RevIt(begin), rit);
                return;
        }
}

template <typename RandomIt>
void Test(RandomIt begin, RandomIt middle, RandomIt end) {
  Test(begin, middle, end, std::reverse_iterator<RandomIt>());
}

int main() {
        std::vector<int> nums = { 2, 1, 123, 1, 23, 123, 123, 5234, 52, 3, 452, 3, 452, 5 };
        int middle;
        std::cin >> middle;
        Test(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+middle, nums.end());
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that the compiler is going through that process of recursively deducing types of nested iterator & reverse iterators. However, its clear that the recursion depth wont exceed 1.

Comment: `its clear that the recursion depth wont exceed 1`..that's the runtime call stack you are talking about, right ? There is no base case here to stop the template recursion.

Comment: There are 2 lists. If the left is larger, essentially switch them. The switch can only happen 0 or 1 time. Also, I don't understand the purpose of the 4th parameter that you've added.

Comment: Victor: the issue is `Merge<it>` calls `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<it>>`, which calls `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<it>>`, which calls `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<it>>>` which calls `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<it>>>>`, which calls....

Comment: You are still talking about the runtime recursion which has nothing to do with code generation at compile time. All that the compiler cares about is generating the code with correct type whenever it encounters a `different` template parameter for that function template. Note that I have stressed on _different_ here. In your original case, the template parameter was keeping on changing, thats why I added the fourth parameter so as to generate the same type so that the compiler won't see different types every time.

Comment: Ah ok Arunmu! I finally see what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is `Merge<it>` requires `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<it>>`, which requires `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<it>>`, which requires `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<it>>>` which requires `Merge<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<std::re‌​verse_iterator<it>>>>`, which requires....

So what you want is for `ReverseIterator(` of an already reversed iterator to use the original iterator. So you need helper functions for that:

```
template <class RandomIt>
RandomIt ReverseIt(std::reverse_iterator<RandomIt> it) {
    return it.base();
}
template <class RandomIt>
std::reverse_iterator<RandomIt> ReverseIt(RandomIt it) {
    return std::reverse_iterator<RandomIt>(it);
}

template<class RandomIt, class Compare=std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type>>
void Merge(RandomIt begin, RandomIt middle, RandomIt end, Compare Comp={}) {
    size_t leftLength = std::distance(begin, middle);
    size_t rightLength = std::distance(middle, end);

    if (leftLength > rightLength) {
        Merge(ReverseIt(end), ReverseIt(std::next(middle)), ReverseIt(begin), Comp);
        return;
    }
    //Now [begin,middle) is guaranteed <= [middle,end)
    //...
}
```

Proof of compilation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741d73f889594e36

Comment: Almost a tangent. In this case, how do you reverse the Compare function? Is it just as simple as passing a lambda that calls Comp with the parameters flipped?

Comment: Good call. Use the same trick: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741d73f889594e36